# Next js public/assets/css doesn't load on dynamically generated pages

Tags: next.js

I am building a Next.js application and starting with an HTML template. I have included the assets in my `Head` and `_document.js` file like so:

```js
<Head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta name="keywords" content={keywords} />
    <meta name="description" content={description} />
    <meta charSet="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="./favicon.ico" />
    <title>{title}</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/plugins.css" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/yourstyle.css" />
</Head>
```

`_document.js`

```js
import Document, { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document'

class MyDocument extends Document {
  static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
    const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx)
    return { ...initialProps }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Html>
        <Head />
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
          <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins.js"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="js/scripts.js"></script>
        </body>
      </Html>
    )
  }
}
```

These files load correctly on all my top level pages but for my dynamically generated posts the files do not load:

> 'Failed to load resource'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really sure why this works but changing my paths from `css/style.css` to `../css/style.css` for all my css and js files worked. Both my scripts and my styles now load on my top level pages and my dynamically generated post pages as well.

Answer (score 0):

Currently you can only import global CSS in `_app.js` shared between all your pages, or use CSS modules in your components (and also CSS in javascript file). But you can't import CSS specific to pages.

You can find examples in [the documentation about CSS in Next.js](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/built-in-css-support).
To import a global CSS file in your `_app.js`, it's like in react, at the top of that file:

```js
import "../styles/main.css";
```

For CSS modules it's the same but in your components, and it affects only that component:

```js
import styles from "../styles/Home.module.css";
```

To have more details, you can read [the RFC that implemented the current way CSS is supported in Next.js](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/8626).

Here is a part of it:

> Next.js will only allow you to import Global CSS within a custom pages/_app.js.
> This is a very important distinction (and a design flaw in other frameworks), as allowing Global CSS to be imported anywhere in your application means nothing could be code-split due to the cascading nature of CSS.
> This is an intentional constraint. Because when global CSS is imported in for example, a component, it will behave different when moving from one page to another.

> Next.js will allow pure CSS Modules to be used anywhere in your application.
> Component-level CSS must follow the convention of naming the CSS file .module.css to indicate its intention to be used with the [CSS Modules specification](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules).

This is only the currrent behavior, development is ongoing. There is [an open ticket to implement global CSS per page](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/20546). You can go there and upvote it.

Comment: Thanks Roman. The additional problem here is the js included in _document.js does not load on a individual post page either. Also, I thought I was already importing the styles globally by included them in a Head tag in _app.js

Comment: Moving all css imports to the top of the file seems to be the solution for me.